# What does ## mean for the C(C++) preprocessor?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

I have a **C** program below:

```
#define f(g,g2) g##g2
main()
{
int var12=100;
printf("%d",f(var,12));
}
```

when I run just the preprocessor it expands  this as

```
{
int var12=100;
printf("%d",var12);
}
```

which is the reason why the output is 100.

Can anybody tell me how/why the preprocessor expands `var##12 to var12`?

Comment: Because that's what `##` means in the C preprocessor.  It's like saying "why does `i++` increment `i`?".  Because the C standard says so!

Comment: @Richo....its not a home work.as i am not much familiar with the preprocessor i had this question in my mind.it might be easy for for you and might look like a homework.but for those who does'nt know this is not so easy to understand.

Comment: I'm sure this is must be duplicate, but of course both google and SO search fail when it comes to searching for ##

Answer (score 35, accepted):

nothing too fancy: `##` tells the preprocessor to concatenate the left and right sides

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation

Answer (score 6):

because ## is a token concatenation operator for the c preprocessor.

Or maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: It concatenates tokens, not strings.

Answer (score 6):

`##` is [Token Pasting Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y(VS.80).aspx)

> The double-number-sign or "token-pasting" operator (##), which is sometimes called the "merging" operator, is used in both object-like and function-like macros. It permits separate tokens to be joined into a single token and therefore cannot be the first or last token in the macro definition.
>
> If a formal parameter in a macro definition is preceded or followed by the token-pasting operator, the formal parameter is immediately replaced by the unexpanded actual argument. Macro expansion is not performed on the argument prior to replacement.

Answer (score 2):

`#define f(g,g2) g##g2`

## is usued to concatenate two macros in c-preprocessor.
So before compiling f(var,12) should replace by the preprocessor with var12 and hence you got the output.