# What is the ## operator?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ## mean for the C(C++) preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025858/what-does-mean-for-the-cc-preprocessor)

```
#define SIMPLE16_DESC_FUNC1(num1, log1) \
    bool                            \
    Simple16::try##num1##_##log1##bit(uint32_t *n, uint32_t len)    \
    {                                       \
            uint32_t        i;              \
            uint32_t        min;            \
\
            min = (len < num1)? len : num1; \
\
            for (i = 0; i < min; i++) {     \
                    if (int_utils::get_msb(n[i]) > log1 - 1)        \
                            return false;   \
            }               \
\
                return true;    \
        }
```

I found this code in someone's code, it seems "##" operator plays an important role in the function name. Anyone tells me what its usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [token pasting operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It concatenates two tokens where one is an argument to the macro.