# Append a string to a variable (function name) in #define MACRO

Tags: c++11, macros

Is it possible to append a string to a *variable* (function/field name) in MACRO?    How?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define T1(hoho) \
   void hoho(){}

#define T2(hoho) \
   void hoho_(){}  //append underscore

T1(happy)
T2(sad)

int main() {
    happy(); //<--- work OK
    sad_();  //<--- this function not exist (compile error)
    return 0;
}
```

I want to use it for some (hacky-but-cool) function generation, e.g. :-

```
#define T3(hoho) \
int hoho_;  \
void hoho_clear(){hoho_=0;}  \
int hoho_get(){return hoho_;}  

class Magic{
    T3(magicField)    //<-- use only 1 MACRO parameter
};
```

The result will be like :-

```
class Magic{
    int magicField_;
    void magicField_clear(){magicField_=0;}
    int magicField_get(){return magicField_;}
};
```

I know it is not a good practice.  I will rarely use it, I promise.

Comment: Use `##`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025858/what-does-mean-for-the-cc-preprocessor

Comment: @kennytm  Thank a lot!!! It works. Should I delete this question?   I am so happy I got answer.  I never know such feature exists. XD

Comment: @kennytm  Is it possible that what come after `##` is a variable that was defined somewhere else?   `#define B C  .... #define T1(A)  A##B`  I can't get it work, guess that it is impossible?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/how-to-concatenate-twice-with-the-c-preprocessor-and-expand-a-macro-as-in-arg   Thank.

Comment: [You should **not** delete the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-good-duplicates).

Comment: @kennytm  Yes, sir!  I will **not** delete it.