# What is the difference between '#include' and '##include'?

Tags: c-preprocessor

For example:

```
#include "pathtoheader1/header1.hh"
##include "pathtoheader2/header2.hh"
```

What is the difference between these two preprocessor directives?

**Edit**

From what I can tell, the ##include directive, in the context of the program I am working with, will prepend -I flags to the specified include path.

```
TRICK_CFLAGS += -Imodels
TRICK_CXXFLAGS += -Imodels
```

The compiler will now look for:

```
/models/pathtoheader1/header1.hh
```

instead of

```
/pathtoheader1/header1.hh
```

These flags are stored in a .mk file.

**Additional Information**

I am using NASA's Trick Simulation environment to build a simple 2-body simulation of the earth orbiting the sun. The specific tool I am using is called 'trick-CP', Trick's compilation tool.

https://github.com/nasa/trick

Comment: The second one won't work.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? And is this C or C++?

Comment: It's not a straight dupe, but it's pretty close, [What does ## mean for the C(C++) preprocessor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025858/what-does-mean-for-the-cc-preprocessor).

Comment: @Bathsheba This is with the gcc compiler.

Comment: One makes sense, the other not.

Comment: What kind of a tool you are using to compile this code?

Comment: @Logman I am using NASA's Trick Simulation environment to build a simple 2-body simulation of the earth orbiting the sun.

https://github.com/nasa/trick

The specific tool I am using is called 'trick-CP', Trick's compilation tool.

Comment: Edit your question and add this information as pure C and C++ do not have this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is about NASA Trick. Trick extends C and C++ language with its own syntax.

From Trick [documentation](https://github.com/nasa/Trick/wiki/TutTrickSimArch):

> Headers files, that supply data-types for user-defined models should be included using  ##include . Note the double hash (#).

Comment: I did not realize that ##include was a Trick specific syntax. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`##` is the *token pasting operator* in both the C and C++ preprocessors. It's used to concatenate two arguments.

Since it requires an argument either side, a line starting with it is not syntactically valid, unless it's a continuation of a previous line where that previous line has used the line continuation symbol `\` or equivalent trigraph sequence.

Comment: Actually, line started with `##` can be syntactically valid inside multiline macro.

Comment: @DAle: naturally.

Comment: Be careful @DAle, because there are multiple applicable definitions of "line" here.  Macro definitions (and indeed all preprocessor directives) are contained entirely on one logical line each.  In that sense, there aren't any multiline macros.  The line continuations by which macro definitions can be spread across multiple physical lines are removed (as if) before tokenizing the input file, so before the preprocessor is ever engaged.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is a syntax error in C++, and I am pretty sure it is a syntax error in C too.  The `##` preprocessor operator is only valid inside a preprocessor macro (where it forces token pasting).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the Trick Documentation says about include:

Include files
There are two types of includes in the S_define file.

Single pound "#" includes.
Include files with a single pound "#" are parsed as they are part of the S_define file. They are treated just as #include files in C or C++ files. These files usually include other sim objects or instantiations as part of the S_define file.

Double pound "#" includes.
Include files with a double pound "##" are not parsed as part of the S_define file. These files are the model header files. They include the model class and structure definitions as well as C prototypes for functions used in the S_define file. Double pound files are copied, minus one pound, to S_source.hh.

Also here is a link to where it talks about it in the Trick documentation: https://nasa.github.io/trick/documentation/building_a_simulation/Simulation-Definition-File