# Why is "##" in C macro needed here and what does semicolon in preprocessed MIPS assembly means?

Tags: assembly, mips, preprocessor

I am recently reading the MIPS assembly for a little OS running on embedded systems based on MIPSfpga.

I have two files, `boot.S` and `boot.h`. I used the command `mips-sde-elf-gcc -c -o boot.o boot.S` to compile it so it would go through the C preprocessor `cpp`.

In the file `boot.h`, it defined a macro :

```
#define LEAF(name)\
    .##text;\
    .##globl    name;\
    .##ent  name;\
name:
```

What does `##` means? I found it on `info cpp` navigate to `Macros` then navigate to `Concatenation`, this is called "token pasting or token concatenation". But why do we need to concatenate token in this situation? You see, the `boot.S` will go through `cpp`, and then `as`. But the `as` also have a built-in token parser, so I don't think this token pasting is necessary here because `as` will parse it as a single symbol, rather than two separate symbols, from the output of `cpp`. `cpp` don't need to bother pasting it.

Then, I used the command `gcc -E boot.S > boot.i` to see what I got after preprocessing. In `boot.S`, the macro `LEAF(__reset_vector)` expanded to the following:

```
.text; .globl __reset_vector; .ent __reset_vector;__reset_vector:
```

The preprocessed directives are on the same line. But what does `;` mean? It is not documented in `info as`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does ## mean for the C(C++) preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025858/what-does-mean-for-the-cc-preprocessor)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thanks. I read that post, it is not duplicated. I am thinking about why `##` is necessary needed here rather than what `##` mean in terms of grammer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the `##` CPP operator is *not* required and has no effect, unless `text`, `globl`, or `ent` are `#define`d as macros.

```
#define LEAF(name)\
    .##text;\
    .##globl    name;\
    .##ent  name;\
name:

LEAF(myname)
```

CPP output: `.text; .globl myname; .ent myname;myname:`

```
#define LEAF2(name)\
    .text;\
    .globl    name;\
    .ent  name;\
name:

LEAF2(myname)
```

CPP output: `.text; .globl myname; .ent myname;myname:`

**The output is identical with or without the `##` token-pasting.**

---

The `;` is a statement separator in this asm syntax (like a newline), so this macro switches to the `.text` section, and declares a global symbol with the macro arg as the name.  There's also a `.ent name` directive in there, and I don't know what it does.

Answer (score 2):

> What does `##` mean?

Create a token out of the preceding and the following one, *pasting* them together. The purpose here is probably to prevent the preprocessor to insert an extra space between the `.` and the following identifier, since `.` is not parsed with the identifier by CPP.

> But what does `;` mean?

In GAS syntax for most architectures, it is a statement separator. Assembly statements are normally separated by newlines, but `cpp`'s macros cannot easily produce multi-line outputs, so another separator is required.

In some other assembly syntaxes (like NASM or MASM), `;` is the comment character.

(Updated based on your additions.)

Comment: Ok. I guess I am being to pedantic here. Maybe viewing the `##` here as a way to prevent unexpected token parsing result is reasonable and will avoid digging too much into `cpp` implementation details.

Comment: CPP wouldn't insert a `.` if you use `.globl` without the `##`.  It's weird and unnecessary, unless you `#define ent foobar` somewhere before this.

Answer (score 1):

I carefully read `info as`. It turns out that "comments and statements" defined by `GNU as` are target specific. Different assembly language may have different comment and statement syntax, as well as line separator. So I need to dig deeper in MIPS syntax.

Comment: As for '##', I guess it is just a double safe here.

Comment: Mmmm... not sure. I can think of a picky preprocessor which would separate the `.` from the following identifier in its output, which would ruins the construction. On the other hand, `.text` as result of the `##` operator is not strictly conforming either (the C standard mandates it to be _one_ C token, which it is not) so it is not completely safe from extra-picky preprocessors either.

Comment: @Han `##` is the *token pasting operator*. It concatenates what comes before and after it into a single token.  Doesn't work here as e.g. `.text` is not a valid token in the C programming language.

Comment: @AntoineL @fuz  Yes, I also assumed that `cpp` would check whether symbols were valid C style identifiers.  However, I did a little test, `#define foo .var=1;printf("%d\n",.var) `, and when I used the command `gcc -E foo.c > foo.i` to preprocess it(expand the macro `foo`), the `cpp` didn't complain `.var` as an invalid identifier. But when I compiled it, `gcc` compiler complained about this and launched an error.

Comment: @fuz @AntoineL Besides, according to `info cpp` then navigate to `Tokenization`, it said "The compiler does not re-tokenize the preprocessor's output. Each preprocessing token becomes one compiler token." . That's what happened when we are compiling `.c` files. `gcc` is a front-end. But when we are compiling `.S` file using gcc, gcc use `as` to compile it. But it is not documented whether `as` will re-tokenize or not.

Comment: @fuz @AntoineL It turns out that `GNU cpp` is not that picky, or it does not check for C style token validity at all. Besides, token pasting can only be used to fool the `cpp` into accepting the ill-named symbol as a valid token rather than the compiler.