# How do these pre-processor defined kernel functions work?

Tags: c, kernel, c-preprocessor, apple-m1, kernel-extension

I am trying to execute some kernel functions on the Apple M1, and have come across
[this](https://gist.github.com/dougallj/5bafb113492047c865c0c8cfbc930155) code which appears to use C macros to define some kernel functions at compile time. These are kernel functions that exist in Apple's `kern/kpc` [library](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1572346-kpc_arch_init), but the header files for this library are not included anywhere, and I believe the API may be private.

I was wondering if anyone could explain how this works, how are the function definitions (ie, the code that would usually be in the function body)  revealed to the program? I am unfamiliar with the `##proc` notation.

```c
#define KPERF_LIST                               \
    /*  ret, name, params */                     \
    F(int, kpc_get_counting, void)               \
    F(int, kpc_force_all_ctrs_set, int)          \
    F(int, kpc_set_counting, uint32_t)           \
    F(int, kpc_set_thread_counting, uint32_t)    \
    F(int, kpc_set_config, uint32_t, void *)     \
    F(int, kpc_get_config, uint32_t, void *)     \
    F(int, kpc_set_period, uint32_t, void *)     \
    F(int, kpc_get_period, uint32_t, void *)     \
    F(uint32_t, kpc_get_counter_count, uint32_t) \
    F(uint32_t, kpc_get_config_count, uint32_t)  \
    F(int, kperf_sample_get, int *)              \
    F(int, kpc_get_thread_counters, int, unsigned int, void *)

#define F(ret, name, ...)                \
    typedef ret name##proc(__VA_ARGS__); \
    static name##proc *name;
KPERF_LIST
#undef F
```

Comment: "I am unfamiliar with the ##proc notation." - Then why do not you read about it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025858/what-does-mean-for-the-cc-preprocessor

Comment: Sorry, I know ## is for concatenation, but I do not understand what the "proc" keyword is doing, or why it should be a typedef

Comment: See documentation of [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) and read about [X macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have contacted the author of the original code to figure this out.

The functions defined by the macro are linked to the kernel library functions later in the code using `dlsym()`. So, the functions are not actually defined in this code; rather, functions *of the same/similar name* are declared and then linked to the kernel library dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

If you have
`F(int, kpc_get_counting, void)`
The first is the type of the returned value. The second is the name of the function and all the following are the parameters.

Comment: I can see how this would define a function signature, but how is the function body/functionality inferred? These are functions which already exist but aren't included by a library and I do not understand how this gives access to them

Comment: They just need to be linked. There are librarys which are linked by default. In most cases from the system itself. The definition (typically done in a header is done there)