# What's the meaning of __asm ("LOS_##_ns")

Tags: c, clang

I'm trying to gain some insight on how Apples OS signpost implementation works. I'm working with the `C` API (there is also a Swift API). My ultimate goal is trying to build a RAII style C++ wrapper class for them, which is harder as it might seem.

Expanding the [os_signpost_emit_with_type macro](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/os_signpost_emit_with_type?language=objc) reveals that it creates static strings from the string literals passed to that macro that look like this:

```
__attribute__((section("__TEXT,__oslogstring,cstring_literals"), internal_linkage)) static const char string_name[] __asm (OS_STRINGIFY(OS_CONCAT(LOS_##_ns, __COUNTER__))) = "string literal";
```

These strings will later appear as names for the signposts in the instruments profiler. What I get from reading that code, is that the string is placed in a specific section of the binary so that the profiler can find it. What's confusing me is the `__asm` statement before the assignment. Obviously via the `__COUNTER__` macro, it expands to something like `__asm ("LOS_##_ns0")`, `__asm ("LOS_##_ns1")` with the number being unique for every string. I have very little in depth knowledge when it comes to assembly, I tried to research the meaning of that statement a bit but got no useful results.

My try-and-error testing revealed that the uniqueness of that numerical appendix generated by the `__COUNTER__` macro matters, if two duplicated values occur the string with that duplicated value will shadow the other one in the profiler output.

Can anyone with assembly know how explain what's going on here to a C++ developer like me?

Bonus question: Would there be any way to generate that instruction from within C++ code where the unique numerical value here generated by `__COUNTER__`would be taken from some variable?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025858/what-does-mean-for-the-cc-preprocessor answer your question?

Comment: No not at all. The `##` characters in the inline assembly instruction string above are no preprocessor string concatenation but actually part of the string literal passed to `__asm()`

Comment: Is this a C or C++ question?  It's tagged as C, but the description keeps referring to C++.

Comment: The code in question is definitively C code. I want to create a C++ wrapper around it in the end, but to do so I first have to understand the meaning of this pure C / inline assembly construct, so I'd consider this a C question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general note: for information on clang extensions, you generally have to refer to the gcc documentation instead.  clang aims to be compatible with gcc and so they didn't bother to write independent docs.

So in your example, a few different extensions are being used.  Note that none of them are part of standard C or C++.

1. `__attribute__((section ("foo"))` places the variable in the section named `foo`, by having the compiler emit a `.section` directive into the assembly before placing the label for the variable.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes.  It sounds like you already know about this.
2. `asm` in a declaration isn't really inline assembly per se; it simply tells the compiler what symbol name to use for this variable when it emits the assembly code.  The `__asm` is just a variant spelling of `asm`.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Asm-Labels.html#Asm-Labels.  So `int foo asm("bar") = 7;` defines a variable which will be referred to as `foo` in C source, but whose label in assembly will be named `bar`.
3. `__COUNTER__` is a special macro defined by the gcc/clang preprocessor that simply increments every time it is expanded.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros

Comment: Thanks, while I was aware of 1. and 3., the meaning of `__asm` in that context was not clear to me. So it seems that for some reasons the assembly variable naming for those signpost strings need to follow that certain pattern.

Is there any chance that the string passed to the `asm` keyword is derived from a template parameter of a surrounding class or must it be a hardcoded string literal?

Comment: Note: I created a separate follow-up question for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75475256/generate-unique-string-literal-for-asm-from-class-template-parameter

Comment: @PluginPenguin: You'd have to try it, but my guess is no, it must be an actual literal (after preprocessor expansion of course).  The [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html#Attribute-Syntax) just say "string constant" without elaborating.