# Generate unique string literal for asm from class template parameter

Tags: c++, assembly, clang, c++20

I have a very special case, where I need to generate a unique assembler name for a variable declared in a class template. I need that name to be unique for every instance of the class template and I need to pass it to the `asm` keyword ([see here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Asm-Labels.html#Asm-Labels)).

My specific case looks somewhat like this:

```
template <size_t n>
struct StringLiteral
{
    constexpr StringLiteral (const char (&str)[n])
    {
        std::copy_n (str, n, value);
    }

    char value[n];
    static constexpr size_t len = n;
};

template <StringLiteral text>
class Foo
{
private:
    template <size_t... i>
    static const char* get (const std::index_sequence<i...>&)
    {
        __attribute__((section("<Some specific section>"), internal_linkage)) static const char t[text.len] asm ("<The unique label>") = { text.value[i]... };
        return t;
    }
public:
    static const char* get()
    {
        return get (std::make_index_sequence<text.len>());
    }
}
```

Where I'd like these three instances to contain three different replacements for `"<The unique label>"` in their `get` function:

```
auto* one = Foo<"Instance One">::get();
auto* two = Foo<"Instance Two">::get();
auto* three = Foo<"Instance Three">::get();
```

To my limited knowledge, it's only possible to pass hard coded string literals as assembler names to `asm`, but maybe someone knows some cool trickery. A name made up of a string prefix with a unique numerical postfix per template instance would be totally fine.

The compiler used is Apple Clang 14, so answers with compiler specific solutions are fine. The code uses C++ 20.

Comment: Do you really need a specific name or do you only need it to be different for each template instantiation? Because the compiler already does the latter.

Comment: This is in the context of building a C++ wrapper for Apple signposts. See my previous question for a bit more context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75469986/whats-the-meaning-of-asm-los-ns/75473629?noredirect=1#comment133173444_75473629

My testing revealed that without a unique asm label per instance, the second string in a translation unit will "shadow" the first one in the profiler output. However, any unique pattern I tried seems to work, so there seems to be no special requirement on how the asm label looks like as long as it's truly unique.

Comment: I don't know Apple signposts. But I repeat that the compiler already gives different variables different names, even inside templates. Otherwise they would be the same variable (the linker would pick one at random and use it for both, or give an error saying there can't be two)

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't explain to you why, but I could clearly see that if the explicit unique asm names are not added, they really occur to be the same variable. Test case: I'm emitting two signposts with different names and inspect them in an Instruments profiling session. Without the explicit assembler name, the profiler will display the first string for both events. With the explicit assembler name, both strings appear as expected. My best guess is that this somehow relates to that special binary section where the signpost name strings are placed.

Comment: What if the variable is not const? The compiler certainly can't make two variables be the same variable if they are not const

Comment: If I go with a non-const variable without an asm name, I get errors like `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/Sparse/SolveImplementation.h:283:7: error: '_os_fmt_str' causes a section type conflict with 't'`. Inspecting that piece of apple framework code reveals that they again add a custom asm label to some log string in there...